# How to do addition of two dates in angular

Tags: angular

How will i do addtion of two dates?

html file

```
<input type="date" #firstdate>
<br>
<input type="date" #seconddate>
<br>

<button (click)="calculate(firstdate.value,seconddate.value)">Add</button>{{result}}
```

typescript file

```
calculate(val1:string,val2:string){
    this.result = parseInt(val1)+parseInt(val2)
  }
```

when I try to add it only add the years.

Comment: so if you add 2023 + 2023 you want the year  4046?

Comment: yes i want all date/month/year

Comment: you can add console.log() for each parsedValue to see what happened